# Spread evenly with margin

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to have is a line with points in it. I'm trying to make it a progress bar but it needs points spread evenly, and `margin:auto` won't do that.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/qj2dwp89/

You can see the progress bar is actually filled for 20%, but it doesn't match the point 20% because the points aren't spread evenly, is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit2: Method 2

Working with flex

```css
.bar-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    background: grey;
}

.bar-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: green;
}

.point-holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.point {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.point::after {
    content: attr(content);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background: red;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-holder">
    <div class="bar-outer">
        <div class="bar-inner"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="point-holder">
        <div class="point" content="20%"></div>
        <div class="point" content="40%"></div>
        <div class="point" content="60%"></div>
        <div class="point" content="80%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Original Answer: Method 1

But that is not how margin works.

Here I used `position:absolute` and `transform:translateX` for text centering.

```css
.bar-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    background: grey;
}

.bar-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background: green;
}

.point-holder {
    position: relative;
    /* display:flex; */
}

.point {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
}

.point:nth-child(1) {
    left: 20%;
}

.point:nth-child(2) {
    left: 40%;
}

.point:nth-child(3) {
    left: 60%;
}

.point:nth-child(4) {
    left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-holder">
  <div class="bar-outer">
    <div class="bar-inner"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="point-holder">
    <div class="point">20%</div>
    <div class="point">40%</div>
    <div class="point">60%</div>
    <div class="point">80%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't used flex here...its just absolute-positioning.

Comment: Why does the progress bar not seem to be completely centered to the point? Am I just seeing things or isn't it actually centered.

Comment: no..you were not only one seeing things.. edited..working perfectly

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have some kind of indicator like a line there to show exactly the middle of lets say 20%, how do I know 20% isn't at the start of 20% box? @CS-CASES.org

Comment: check different values..like 40% or 80% in `.bar-inner {width:40%;}` and you will get an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Just found some old Javascript code in my library. It will do the job regarding a smooth "loading" of the load bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Progress bar</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <style>
        body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            background:#333;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
            position: relative;
            background: #333;
        }
        #progress {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 8px;
            background: rgba(51, 151, 251, 0.395);
        }
        #progress-bar {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background: rgba(51,151,255,1.0);
            height: 8px;
            width: 10%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            function animate(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
                if( !elem) return;
                var start = new Date().getTime(),
                    timer = setInterval(function() {
                        var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
                        elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
                        if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
                    },25);
                elem.style[style] = from+unit;
            }

            animate(
                document.getElementById('progress-bar'),
                "width","%",0,100,2500
            );



        };

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="container">

        <h1 style="font-size:40px; position:absolute; width:10vw; left:45vw; text-align:Center; top:250px; font-family:arial; color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); font-weight:normal;">0%</h1>

            <div id="progress">
                <div id="progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what has this to do with the points, the bar is not my problem in this case.

Comment: Sry bruh, only read the post briefly. At least we all get to see my nice load bar haha. Sry

Comment: Haha, the ones that actually take the time to copy the code and run it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The divs are actually evenly spread, but the percentage points inside are not.

`margin:auto;` is evenly spacing the divs and placing the percentage values in the middle.

A simple fix is to left pad them, since the right-most side of the div will be the 20% margin. So instead of `margin:auto;` you can try `margin-left:17%` which looks about right. In order for it to be perfect every time, even if the font changed, you would probably need to use Javascript.

Note that this may not appear correct on mobile.

https://jsfiddle.net/qj2dwp89/3/

Comment: I need it to be exact, points should be exact in the middle since I'm doing a live progress bar that actually counts up to 100%, the points will be points like 17.38% and they have to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight modification to clearify the 20% mark. If you take a look at this jsfiddle you will see it more clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/50b0qjgg/1/

```
.bar-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ededed;
}

.bar-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.point-holder {
    position: relative;
}

.point {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: lightcoral;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
}

.point:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 1px;
 background-color: lightcoral;
 height: 3px;
 top: -3px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.point:nth-child(1) {
    left: 20%;
}

.point:nth-child(2) {
    left: 40%;
}

.point:nth-child(3) {
    left: 60%;
}

.point:nth-child(4) {
    left: 80%;
}
```

Comment: That's still not entirely what I'm looking for the green should be exactly in the middle of the points.

Comment: @CS-CASES.org added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just add `justify-content: space-evenly;` to `.point-holder`

```
.point-holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; /* add */ 
}
```

and would be nice you fix the width of the div (`.point`) and remove `margin: auto`, it's not needed.

```
.point{
  background:red;
  margin:auto; /* remove */ 
  color:white;
  padding:3px;
  width: 24px; /* add */ 
  font-size: 12px /* add */ 
}
```